# "Óleo canola" ou "óleo de canola"?

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas, preposições, origem-histórica

Pesquisando a expressão "óleo de canola" no Google fez retornar resultados com "óleo de canola", e a Wikipédia retornou "óleo canola".

Qual deles está correto, e por que?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Óleo de canola é que está correto.

**Canola** é uma planta, logo a palavra é um substantivo. Só faria sentido dizer *óleo canola* se *canola* fosse um adjetivo. Faria tanto sentido dizer *óleo canola* como dizer *óleo palma* ou *óleo soja*.

Na verdade, o [artigo na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%93leo_canola), apesar de ter como título *óleo canola" utiliza *óleo de canola* no texto.

Comment: O estranho é que não achei nenhuma menção a uma planta chamada "canola". Apenas ao óleo.

Comment: Está no artigo da Wikipédia logo [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%93leo_canola#Hist.C3.B3ria). É uma variedade de colza.

Answer (score -2):

CANOLA nao é planta nenhuma. Significa Can(adian) + o(il) + l(ow) + a(cid. Entao o certo é OLEO CANOLA. Ou pode ser dito OLEO DE COLZA.

Comment: No meu entendimento não deixa de ser uma espécie de planta: uma variedade da colza (Brassica rapa).

Comment: Sim colza é um planta. A questao nao é a planta... É  o nome CANOLA que nao tem nada haver com a planta. É como um apelido que significa CAN adian Oleo L pouco A acido. Entao canola nao é planta e um tipo de oleo classificado no Canada.

Comment: O Canola Council do Canadá [afirma outra coisa](https://www.canolacouncil.org/oil-and-meal/what-is-canola/): "The plant belongs to the Brassica genus".   
E também a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canola#Hist.C3.B3ria): "Canola é um cultivar de colza criado para ter baixo teor de ácido erúcico."
Ou seja, você está certo ao afirmar que não é uma planta específica, mas esse tipo de ambiguidade e imprecisão é comum na nomenclatura (popular e/ou comercial) de plantas e animais.